# Header Footer Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel for the first time

i have to make a Front End Menu Dynamic in Header and Footer [ list of categories will come from database ]. which controller I have to use for this.?
any common controller available in this framework to send data to header and footer.

When I receive the data in HomeController index Action its available for the home page only.

```
class HomeController {
public function index() 
    {
        $categories = Category::get();
        return view('home', compact('categories'));
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try [these](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=menu+build+in+laravel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=hUchWsSVNaWdX4Lyi_AC)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a perfect case for [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers):

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize that logic into a single location.

You may attach a view composer to multiple views at once by passing an array of views as the first argument to the composer method:

```
View::composer(['partials.header', 'partials.footer'], function ($view) {
    $view->with('categories', [1, 2, 3]); // bind data to view
});
```

Now you could simply retrieve `$categories` within your view (blade template).

Tip: Common practice is to create a new service provider called `ComposerServiceProvider` and place the abovementioned composer logic in the `boot()` method.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using the Header and Footer in a master layout file. In this case you need to send all header/footer info every request. Which would be silly so instead use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers):

Define them in your `appServiceProvider` in the `boot()` method

```
view()->composer('home', function($view) {
   $view->with('categories', App\Category::all());
});
```

In my example i made `'home'` the name of the view, since it is in your example. But i would make a master file called layout and include a header and footer partial. If you want categories inside your header you could make a `view()->composer('layout.header')` with only header data.

Answer (score 0):

> which controller I have to use for this.?

Any

> any common controller available in this framework to send data to header and footer

No.
You control what is returned from the Controller to be the response. You can design layouts and break them up into sections and have views that extend them. If you setup a layout that has the header and footer and your views extend from it, you can use a View Composer to pass data to that layout when it is rendered so you don't have to do this every time you need to return a view yourself.

[Laravel Docs 5.5 - Front End - Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#template-inheritance)

[Laravel Docs 5.5 - Views - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 0):

In case of this u can use components

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components

```
php artisan make:component Header
```

View/Component.Header.php

```
public function render()
{
    $category = [Waht you want];
    return view('views.header', ['category'=>$category]);
}
```

Then include Header.php to your blade like this
views/front.blade.php

```
<html>
    <body>
        <x-header/> <!-- like this -->
        @yield('content')
        @include('footer')
    <body>
```