# Laravel trying to get navbar list from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, controller, laravel-5.4

I have a navbar which is included in `master.blade.php` page. In my navbar I want to do something like

```
  @if(count($cats)> 0)
    @foreach($cats as $cat)
      <a href="#">{{$cat->name}}</a>
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

But I don't know how to get the controller used for every view.
Because `navbar.blade.php` is **included** after all. it doesn't use a route.

Controller name is `CatsController` and the function is `cats`.

I will probably need to get the list of categories using *jquery* or *javascript*. But I don't know how am I going to do that. Unfortuantely I forgat a lot about js

> Laravel 5.4

Thanks for any help.

Comment: why do you need javascript?

Comment: @lagbox I guess I need to access the controller with database and get the navbar list  and pass it to view without needing route, otherways I don't know how I will return navbar content for navbar which doesn't use route. and without route I don't know how I will access the controller.

Comment: what does 'without needing a route' mean ... requests get dispatched to routes, every view gets rendered and returned via routing  ... why does clicking matter ... what part of this is dynamic at all?

Comment: @lagbox I'm sorry I don't know what you are trying to actually point. The question I'm asking is: How I can get navbar list from database which is included in master. Since it is included in master, that navbar is used in each view. Si I need something that will work in every page. otherways I will need to return navbar content for each page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use belows code in your `navbar.blade.php`. You dont have to use jquery or ajax, when you get data without controller

```
@php($cats = App\Cats::all())
 @if(count($cats)> 0)
    @foreach($cats as $cat)
      <a href="#">{{$cat->name}}</a>
    @endforeach
  @endif
```

Edit category model name, if its exist with another name name

Comment: Now that I think this would actually work too. I used some other method and solved my problem. but thanks for this one too

Comment: I tried this method too it works pretty well. I don't know if it is safe but yeah it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use javascript ajax

Comment: Yeah that is what I think too, but I don't know how do I access controller function from javascript

Comment: If you don't know the answer can you up my question so I get better chance fo having the question answered.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to have data available to a layout without having to pass it from Controller to every view that extends that layout?

A View Composer would be the way to go if you have a layout that things are extending from and would like to pass data to that layout automatically.

[Stackoverflow question similar in nature about needing data for header and footer of layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47593072/header-footer-controller-in-laravel)

```
View::composer('layouts.main', function ($view) {
    $view->with('cats', Cat::all());
});
```

The layout will now have a `$cats` Collection to use.

[Laravel 5.5 Docs - View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers)

Comment: Ahhh yeah I guess that is what I need. I use `View:composer` like a route inside `web.php`  right?

Comment: no, i would follow the doc links from the answers in that post or the doc link here